# Как заставить блок растягиватся по всей ширине?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Если сузить окно меньше, чем на 1000px, появится горизонтальный скролл, если его подвинуть то видно, что `div` растягивает `body` больше, чем область видимости, но `header` не растягивается вслед за ним. Как это можно исправить?

https://jsfiddle.net/z2rrrcf3/2/

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  align-self: stretch;
  min-width: 110px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div></div>
```

Comment: убрать у div width: 1000px;

Comment: Нет, контент фиксированный

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 900px){ ....}`

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1

Добален абсолютный размер  `width: 819px`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  align-self: stretch;
  min-width: 110px;
  width: 819px;
  height: 100px;
}

div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div></div>
```

Comment: А как это работает?

Comment: что конкретно?.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 2

Здесь добавлен внешний `<div>`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  align-self: stretch;
  min-width: 110px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}


div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<header></header>
<div></div>
</div>
```